# Can OS X audio preview loop or be replaced by a different playback system that supports looping?

Tags: audio, osx

I'm working with single cycle waveforms which don't seem to work with Preview. The stop/start is done before audio is produced. I'd like a tool that offers an improvement on the native playback. Anything out there? I'm familiar with Iced Audio Audiofinder but that is a bit excessive for my needs.

Comment: By "Preview", do you mean QuickLook? The Preview app doesn't read audio files.

Comment: Yes! For some reason I've always thought Preview was at the heart of it of the rendering. My error.

Comment: My use of 'Preview' instead of the proper feature name 'Quicklook' may have suggested I was looking for a stand alone app. I think what I need is actually a Quicklook plugin which supports audio looping. I don't want to have to launch an app to preview loops if possible.

Comment: One of the reasons I suggest QuickTime is because it's a very lightweight app, and audio files will open very quickly if the app is already open.

Comment: Understood, and yet I have thousands of these waveforms and using the finder+spacebar(quicklook)+down-arrow behavior which I've used traditionally for listening to mp3s/aiff/wav, reading files, etc, is great. If I wanted to open an App I would use AudioFinder which is a far more comprehensive utility for managing large numbers of files.

Answer (score 1):

For simple, reliable audio playback, I actually still use QuickTime.

If you don't like QuickTime X that is included on all new Macs (and I don't), you can still get [QuickTime 7](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL923?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), which also has available some very worthy ["Pro" functions](https://www.apple.com/quicktime/extending/), for a [$30 activation key](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D3380Z/A/quicktime-7-pro-for-mac-os-x). Looping should work without Pro.

QuickTime Pro 7 is still highly useful to me even after all these years--the reason it is still around is because QuickTime X was a complete rewrite that matched with Apple's new style for its media applications, but it did not contain all of the features that are present in QuickTime 7.

Answer (score -1):

For looping, I would use Logic if you have it. if not, Garageband will do the job.

For simple audio playback there is always iTunes and a host of alternatives, such as these listed here:
http://www.head-fi.org/t/539740/mac-os-x-music-players-alternatives-to-itunes.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Garageband doesn't allow you to preview audio files that aren't Apple Loops. Logic9 doesn't offer a single-cycle preview. Instead, you have to import single-cycle samples into a project's bin, and then you can play them. The list of music players you linked covers players intended for listening to full tracks, not extremely short single-cycle loops.